# Grails "if no errors" and login newly created user

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

How would I make a logic block that only executes if there are no errors (from the gsp)?

Also, after creating a user how would I automatically log them in using **Spring Security Core Plugin**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that depends on the error, for instance if a serverside validation fails
you can return the error as a boolean to your gsp like:

```
    try {
        xyzService.saveAndUpdateStatistics(stats)
        redirect(controller:'statistic', action:'stats')
    } catch(ValidationException vex) {
        Boolean error = true
        render(view: "stats", model:[stats:stats,error:error])    
    }
```

then you can simply use sth like

```
<g:if test="${!error}">
  <g:textField name="noError" value="no-Error" />
</g:if>
```

and your second question, why would you want to log them with springsecuritycore plugin ? 
everytime you create a new user using springssecurity or else i would use
The logging plugin wich makes use of Apache log4j

```
def user = new User()
user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
log.info "User saved : "+user
```

http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Plug-ins/logging.html

http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html